# how to get the top 10 of the day C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, charts, datatable

I have a table in SQL server:

| date_Tim| Machine|Case_wrong|

|:---------|:--------:|:----------:|

|07/03/21 16:53:PM|Test1|1|

|07/03/21 16:58:PM|Test1|1|

|07/03/21 16:59:PM|Test1|1|

|07/03/21 16:58:PM|Test2|1|

|07/03/21 16:59:PM|Test2|1|

|07/03/21 17:00:PM|Test2|1|

|07/03/21 17:01:PM|Test3|1|

|08/03/21 16:58:PM|Test3|1|

|08/03/21 16:58:PM|Test2|1|

I want to sum column machine All machine from date 07/03/22 and fill to chart
I try code

```
  private void loadchart()
        {
            var Today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
            ChartTop.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            ChartTop.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = con;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            try
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 Machine, Sum(Case_wrong) as Case_wrong FROM tbl_Count_" + cbWorkcell.Text + " group by Machine order by SUM(Case_wrong)";
                DataSet dtRecord = new DataSet();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                ChartTop.DataSource = dtRecord;
                //set the member of the chart data source used to data bind to the X-values of the series  
                ChartTop.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Machine";
                //set the member columns of the chart data source used to data bind to the X-values of the series  
                ChartTop.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Case_wrong";
             //   ChartTop.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

it works but it takes all the data in my table for calculation. is there a way to filter the data by date and sum there?
Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a SQL question but you have tags for C#, and various UI things. Consider retagging to get more targeted attention, and reducing your post to just the parts relative to the query itself.

Comment: Also, you have a serious SQL injection vulnerability. You're taking user input and, without validating it, including it directly in the query.  Must read: https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Yes. I'm newbie so I need to learn more

Comment: Well, it is about how to do the query from C#, and we do see C# source here, so no, don't remove the C# tag. But the other tags can go. You need to protect the query related objects (e.g. SqlConnection) with using-statements. Your query should contain a where clause that limits date_Tim to within the day you want. Use >=  than the date and < the next date.

Comment: Can you advise the full query?  I just need to get the current date

Comment: Just from a cursory look, we couldn't tell you if it is possible to filter by date because we don't know the schema for your table. if there is a date field then I'd add a where clause to your sql string. (also yes this is insecure and you should use sql query params). 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: in my table there is a dateTime column.  but I don't know "where" to put where in query

Comment: Query im using: SELECT TOP 10 Machine, Sum(Case_wrong) as Case_wrong FROM tbl_Count_Casewrong group by Machine order by SUM(Case_wrong)

Comment: Side points: you need to dispose your connection, command and adapter with `using`. And needing to dynamically access a table where all tables have the same columns is a sign of poor database design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears is that date_Tim is a datetime feild , if thats the case then you need a `where` clause added to your query , I am assuming that the date you mentioned (07/03/22) is DD/MM/YY based on that the query needs to be updated to add the clause as below

```
"SELECT TOP 10 Machine, Sum(Case_wrong) as Case_wrong FROM tbl_Count_" + cbWorkcell.Text + " WHERE date_Tim >='2022-03-07 00:00:00.000'  group by Machine order by SUM(Case_wrong)"
```

Please note @madreflection has pointed out critical errors, please fix them more details about SQL injection [here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection)

Edit 1:
In case you are just looking for a specific day

```
"SELECT TOP 10 Machine, Sum(Case_wrong) as Case_wrong FROM tbl_Count_" + cbWorkcell.Text + " WHERE CAST(date_Tim AS DATE)  ='2022-03-07'  group by Machine order by SUM(Case_wrong)"
```

In case you are looking for the current date

```
"SELECT TOP 10 Machine, Sum(Case_wrong) as Case_wrong FROM tbl_Count_" + cbWorkcell.Text + " WHERE CAST(date_Tim AS DATE)  = GETDATE()  group by Machine order by SUM(Case_wrong)"
```

Comment: sorry but I tried your query but the results are still the same.  my date_Time column is in the format of (dd/MM/yy HH:mm:tt)

Comment: Tell us a little more about the data you have, and the results you see. In your question rows from 2021-03-07 and 08 are shown, while you want results for 2022-03-07.

Comment: @QuânNè : Like Bent mentioned,  please provide more details on what is needed, are  you looking at data after 2022-03-07? or only for a specific day ? only for current day when the query run ? , That can help us clarify response